# include file 'string' not found

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

Learning C++, day 1, lesson 2

My simple string concatenation test works on the [online c++ compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{

    // Declare and initialize string
    std::string mystr = "bananas";
    
    std::cout << "Gwen Stefani is " << mystr << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Which works fine: `Gwen Stefani is bananas` as expected. However, using [Tiny CC](https://bellard.org/tcc/) I get the error:

```
Error: include file 'string' not found
```

Still new to compilers, all being equal... So I'm a little confused as to what's gone wrong.

Comment: C is actually a different language from C++, despite their common origin and many similarities.

Comment: "Tiny C" is a C compiler, not C++. Different languages.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if Tiny C Compiler was supporting C++, it would not be *tiny* anymore.

Comment: I'm aware that C and C++ are like Car and Carpet. However, I jumped to the assumption that tiny CC was was for both C and C++. My bad. Ooops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiny CC is a C compiler, it does not support C++.

Since `<string>` is a C++ standard header, it is not supported by Tiny CC.

Comment: Nor would it support `<iostream>`, and thus `std::cout`, etc